# Django: Template doesn't exist but on production

Tags: python, django, heroku

I have started another app inside my django project, and i already have multiple apps inside but only one return template doesnt exit but on production only, my project is deployed on heroku.

I have done million of searches but couldnt find the solution.

my static files and database are hosted on AWS

settings.py

```
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'erecruit',
    'compensation',
    'PMS',
    'crispy_forms',
    'forms_fieldset',
    'django_filters',
    'storages',
    'gunicorn',
    'foundation_filefield_widget',
]
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        # 'DIRS': [BASE_DIR + "/templates", ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'xxxx'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'xxx'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'xxxxx'
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = 'public-read'
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = f'{AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME}.s3.amazonaws.com'
AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400'}

AWS_LOCATION = 'static'
STATIC_URL = f'https://{AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN}/{AWS_LOCATION}/'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = "storages.backends.s3boto3.S3StaticStorage"

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False
AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False
AWS_S3_VERIFY=False
AWS_S3_USE_SSL = False

STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')

django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

view.py

```
@login_required(login_url='loginPage')
def home(request):
    perm = 0
    for i in request.user.groups.all():
        if i.name == 'PMSupervisors': perm = 1
    if perm == 0:
        context = {}
        return render(request, 'PMS/pms_home.html',context)
    if perm == 1:
        print('this username is a supervisor')
        context = {}
        return redirect('supervisor_home')
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('PMS/', include('PMS.urls')),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_URL)

urlpatterns = [path('', views.home, name='PMS-home'),]
```

here is a picture of the error
[image: Django Error]

Comment: Please show full error message, elaborate which URL you're trying to access and show corresponding urls.py contents

Comment: I had the same error a few times. This is because Heroku uses PostGres databases and your local version is probably on SQL. You need to give Heroku a bit more information on the path where to find your template. Would be interesting to have your answer if you figure it out. (I can't help you more than that I'm afraid)

Comment: @IvanStarostin i have added the picture of the error, also added my urls at the end

Comment: @PhilM i am working on postgres hosted on AWS in both local and porduction